# Can anyone know how to see the data in a cluster after doing k-means clustering?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, k-means

Is there any code to see or view the data in a cluster after doing k-means clustering in python,
so that i can know which type of data clustered into which cluster and why.

help me with this ?

The cluster file is in .File extension, so I am unable to open it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's unclear how the `.File` file is related to the question. If you have a 2D dataset and want to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74748826/how-to-visualize-cluster-boundaries/74748921#74748921) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580741/colormap-scatter-plot-dependant-on-cluster-membership/74803727#74803727) but with KMeans, there are a couple tweaks that can be made. Edit your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are doing Kmeans... however... the attribute which shows the categorical cluster assignments (or "labels") are:

`KMeans().fit().labels_`

#### Code: ([source here](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-k-means-clustering-in-machine-learning-6a6e67336aa1))

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
%matplotlib inline

X= -2 * np.random.rand(100,2)
X1 = 1 + 2 * np.random.rand(50,2)
X[50:100, :] = X1
plt.scatter(X[ : , 0], X[ :, 1], s = 50)
plt.show()

Kmean = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X)
print(Kmean.labels_)
```

#### Output:

[image: chart]

`Kmean.labels_`

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

If you were to put the `X`, `X1` and `labels_` into a **dataframe**, it would look like this:

```
           X        X1  Labels
0  -1.918458 -1.918458       0
1  -1.378906 -1.378906       0
2  -0.888738 -0.888738       0
3  -1.924301 -1.924301       0
4  -0.619357 -0.619357       0
..       ...       ...     ...
95  1.893219  1.893219       1
96  2.820921  2.820921       1
97  2.454180  2.454180       1
98  1.599229  1.599229       1
99  2.270729  2.270729       1

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Any predicted values or any values has features to make color maps in general can do this all of what you need is to make color equals to your color theme list and your labeler like this (the relabeler is just for make ground truth data colors like the predicted ones):

```
MyColorTheme = np.array(["darkgrey", "lightsalmon", "powderblue"])
MyRelabeler = np.choose(MyCluster.labels_, [2, 0, 1]).astype(np.int64)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.title("My Ground Truth Classification Module")
plt.scatter(x = MyDataFrame[["Petal Length"]], y = MyDataFrame[["Petal 
Width"]], c = MyColorTheme[MyData.target], s = 50)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.title("K clustring Classification Module")
plt.scatter(x = MyDataFrame[["Petal Length"]], y = MyDataFrame[["Petal 
Width"]], c = MyColorTheme[MyRelabeler], s = 50)
```

**Output:**
[image: Iris SpectralClustering method from sklearn]